# How to preprocess credit card and extract numbers without background

Tags: opencv, preprocessor, ocr

I'm trying to make a credit card ocr engine like Card.io . But it is very tough to preprocess the card into binary image without noise. I use SWT algorithm but it not works well for all the card. There are variety of credit cards with low contrast background and embossed number. It is very hard to design a common algorithm to preprocess card well for OCR.So dose any one have experience on this kind of card process. The image below is the example of card which is hard for me to preprocess
[image]
[image]

Comment: I can't think in any legal reason to do CC OCR.

Comment: It just like card.io, this is a new way for payment in mobile device. I just want to talk about the technique, I do not want to discuss the legal here

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that credit cards are on purpose so hard to read (therefore to process). The best I could do was, transforming them to greyscale and add some horizontal sobel filter and then maybe play with some more transformations. And still it was difficult to extract the binary image with the numbers only... And it definitely have different outcome from image to image... 
Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

I know i am late but found the solution in adrian rosebrock's blog post over here -

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/07/17/credit-card-ocr-with-opencv-and-python/

The technique is to perform template matching with opencv
then filter the credit card image using grayscale, morphology operations and thresholding.

Then we can find contours of our interest that means contours with relevent height:width ratio.

Once we have got contours of our interest (contours with group of digits) we can again find and extract individual digits. Then we can compare these digits with the digits n our template image.

And in this way we can OCR a credit card

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @Mithrandir i edited the answer. I feel thats sufficient as everything else is explained in the blog